# Why is "from pykinect2 import PyKinectV2 " not working?

Tags: python, kinect, kinect-sdk, kinect-v2, pykinect

I'm trying right now using PyCharm IDE to just turn on my camera Kinect v2 using PyKinect2, but I can't. If they are is any solution can you help me? This is the code:

```
import pygame
from pykinect2 import PyKinectV2
```

Comment: `C:\Users\ME\PycharmProjects\kinect2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\ME\PycharmProjects\kinect2\main.py 
pygame 2.5.2 (SDL 2.28.3, Python 3.8.6)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ME\PycharmProjects\kinect2\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pykinect2 import PyKinectV2
  File "C:\Users\ME\PycharmProjects\kinect2\venv\lib\site-packages\pykinect2\PyKinectV2.py", line 2216, in <module>
    assert sizeof(tagSTATSTG) == 72, sizeof(tagSTATSTG)
AssertionError: 80
Process finished with exit code 1
`

Comment: this is not a comment. edit your question and add that there

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to an error. When pykinectv2 is installed it using `pip install PyKinectV2` command. To fix it please do the following.

Go to the pykinect2 installation in the site-packages folder
**(C:\Users\ME\PycharmProjects\kinect2\venv\lib\site-packages\pykinect2)**
and replace the files with .py extension files with the ones from the github repository. This should solve the problem.
Link: https://github.com/Kinect/PyKinect2